# UnZip/Extract Zip file in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, zip, unzip

I have a zip file containing a folder and inside the folder I have some image file.I wish to extract these images.However I have not been able to find anything.I have been looking at zipMe but have not been able to find any relevant help.

Below is the code that I have developed so far.

```java
    ZipEntry dataZE;
    InputStream isData;
    StringBuffer sbData;
    ZipInputStream dataZIS;

    String src = "file:///store/home/user/images.zip";
    String path = "file:///store/home/";
    String fileName = "";
    FileConnection f_Conn;

    public UnZipper() {

        debugger("Unzipper constructor");

        try {
            f_Conn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(src);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("f_conn error :" + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            isData = f_Conn.openInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("f_conn error getting ip_stream:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        sbData = new StringBuffer();

        dataZIS = new ZipInputStream(isData);

        debugger("got all thing initialized");

    }

    public void run() {

        debugger("unzipper run");

        try {
            startUnziping();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            debugger("Error unzipping " + e.getMessage());
        }

        debugger("finished...");

    }


    private void startUnziping() throws IOException {

        debugger("startUnziping");
        dataZE = dataZIS.getNextEntry();
        fileName = dataZE.getName();
        writeFile();
        dataZIS.closeEntry();

        debugger(">>>>>>>>>>> : " + fileName);
    }

    private void readFile() throws IOException {

        debugger("readFile");
        int ch;
        int i = 0;
        while ((ch = dataZIS.read()) != -1) {

            debugger((i++) + " : " + sbData.toString()
                    + " >>> writting this..");
            sbData.append(ch);
        }

    }

    private void writeFile() {

        debugger("writting file...");
        FileConnection f_Conn = null;
        byte[] file_bytes = new byte[sbData.length()];
        file_bytes = sbData.toString().getBytes();

        try {
            readFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("Error while reading " + e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            f_Conn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("getting f_conn" + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (!f_Conn.exists()) {
            // create the file first
            debugger("I know file does not exists");
            try {
                f_Conn.mkdir();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                debugger("Oops!!! error creating fle : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        try {
            f_Conn.setWritable(true);
            debugger("file is nt writeable");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("cannot make it writeable : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        OutputStream lo_OS = null;
        try {
            lo_OS = f_Conn.openOutputStream();
            debugger("got out Stream hero!!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("cant get out Stream !!!");
        }
        try {
            lo_OS.write(file_bytes);
            debugger("yess...writtent everything");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            add(new LabelField("Error writing file ..." + e.getMessage()));
        }
        try {
            lo_OS.close();
            debugger("now closing connection...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            debugger("error closing out stream : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

I have been able to get ZipEntry representing folder that contains images however I have not been able to figure out how i must extract those images.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over all `ZipEntry` in zip file in you `startUnzipping` (you're working only with first one in your code). The item corresponded to child file should have name like "***foldername***/***filename***".